# How to map a collection with one extra column in an intermediate table

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I'm trying to map the objects to the following join table,

Table name: **booking_pax**
3 Columns: **booking_id**, **pax_id**, **pax_no_in_tour**
Primary Key: **booking_id**, **pax_id**
Foreign Key: **booking_id** ref booking table, **pax_id** ref pax table

```
CREATE TABLE `booking_pax` (
  `booking_id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `pax_id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `pax_numb_in_tour` int(2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`booking_id`,`pax_id`),
  KEY `booking_booking_pax` (`booking_id`),
  KEY `pax_booking_pax` (`pax_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `booking_booking_pax` FOREIGN KEY (`booking_id`) REFERENCES `booking` (`booking_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `pax_booking_pax` FOREIGN KEY (`pax_id`) REFERENCES `pax` (`pax_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

I have two entities: *pax* and *booking*. Due to the relationship is ManyToMany, and there is one extra column need to add into this join table.
Now I have problem to mapping with Hibernate.

Modelling:

```
@Entity
public class Booking {
    ......

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="booking_pax",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="booking_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="pax_id")}
    )
    //@ElementCollection
    //@Column(name="pax_numb_in_tour")
    public Map<Pax, Integer> getPaxs() {
        return paxs;
    }
    ......
}
```

The error msg:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.....model.Booking.paxs[java.lang.Integer]
```

I have tried many ways to map the collection, but still not working.
The IDE I'm using is MyEclipse 8.6 with JaveEE 5. I tried to upgrade to JavaEE 6 but failed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

untested:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(
    name="booking_pax",
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="booking_id")}
)
@Column(name="pax_numb_in_tour")
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name="pax_id")
public Map<Pax, Integer> getPaxs() {
    return paxs;
}
```